# Hibernate and Mysql timeout problem, doesn't work with c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, c3p0

I have been having trouble with Hibernate and Mysql timeout error for a week. 
Apparently, After my Hibernate/MySQL have been running after 8 hours(which is default timeout value in Mysql), I have the exception. I also added c3p0. But it doesn't help.

Please advice
Thank you so much

Here is my Hibernate Configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<!--Account MYSQL Username Info-->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/reddragon_test?autoReconnect=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>
```

Here is the trace:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at com.billing.dao.VmplanDAO.findByExample(VmplanDAO.java:178)
    at com.billing.action.getVmplans.processRequest(getVmplans.java:37)
    at com.billing.action.getVmplans.doGet(getVmplans.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2428)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2882)
    ... 38 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.billing.action.getVmplans.processRequest(getVmplans.java:38)
    at com.billing.action.getVmplans.doGet(getVmplans.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730827/hibernate-c3p0-mysql-broken-pipe

Comment: Settings look fine. Are you sure that Hibernate is using the cfg file you expect it is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be very honest there are three solutions to your problems. I will explain each solution and pros and cons of every solution (will come to your case in last)

1. configure wait_time_out property in mysql my.ini file to make sure your connections are timed out. This approach will definitely work but no way this is a good solutions. you would love to handle this thing in your application rather than in database because at times you might not be having that much control over the database or some other application might be using the same database.
2. Use apache dbcp instead of c3p0. You can configure the dbcp in context.xml of your server where you give name of the database. This approach will work but problem with this approach is you might plan to switch to some other application server say JBOSS in future, in that case i am not apache dbcp will work or not. I have not tried it with jboss but guess is it won't.
3. Third way is what you have opted for

In your case you are missing one property, that is

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">
  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
</property>
```

Till now you must have noticed during your server startup that c3p0 is not initialized at all. Well if you are thinking after setting this property your code will work, I am sorry to say, it will not.

This is due to a bug in spring code. you can verify this by looking at the source code of LocalSessionFactoryBean, where it simply ignore the value of property set above and sets it to LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider and your c3p0 is never initialized.

You can provide the custom implementation of LocalSessionFactoryBean , where you can hard code the provider class to C3P0ConnectionProvider.

Now restart the server and note your c3p0 is initialized and now you can deal with c3p0 details.

Problem till now with you is that c3p0 is never initialized and is out of picture.

Hope this helps.